# Convert classes relationships in Java into database schema

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, hibernate-mapping

What is the best tool/framework to convert classes into database schema automatically without XML mapping files?

My problem is this, I have around 20 classes with different relationships (association, inner classes, etc) to each others and I want to convert all that into a database tables to save all these data along with its relationships.

I tried to see some tutorials to Hibernate and found out that it requires building a mapping XML which is going to be very painful to my case.

Any framework to automate this?

Comment: It sounds like you could use a database refactoring before you approach an abstraction.

Comment: 1) Hibernate does not require mapping files anymore (you can use annotations). 2) You might want to check out [JPA](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/tech/persistence-jsp-140049.html), it allows you to write vendor independent ORM code, and only requires a small configuration file to setup.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can annotate your classes instead of using XML and then generate the schema from your entities. Anyway, I strongly recommend writing the classes in a way that is easy to use with an OR mapper. It would have been best to design your model for the use of Hibernate beforehand.